# Concatenate CASE values in SQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to put the matching case values in a variable in T-SQL.
So my scenario is ,
If the case is MATCHED then it should be kept in varibales and if not then skip the case statement .
So i am trying to concatenate all the matched cases and keep the result in one @Result varible.
Here is my sql query for that:

```
declare @result varchar(200)
set @result=''

select 
    case 
        when 1=1 then @result=@result+'CASE 1' 
        when 1=2 then @result=@result+'CASE 2' 
        when 2=2 then @result=@result+'CASE 3'
    end
```

Here I need a result like :
CASE 1 ; CASE 3
As CASE 1 and CASE 3 are matched and CASE 2 is not matching.

But after running this query i got the error as :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near '='.

Could anyone help me to run this query ?

Comment: That's invalid syntax. To assign a value to a variable you should use `SELECT` or `SET`, eg `SELECT @result = …`. This isn't a *query* though. It won't concatenate anything. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you want to store query results in a variable, use a table variable, not a string. `INSERT into @myTable(a,b,c) SELECT a,b,c from someTable where …` works with table variables in the same way it works with tables

Comment: `CASE` is an expression not a statement. It returns a scalar value, it doesn't perform a logical operation or return boolean result. SQL is not a programming language.

Comment: I have a multiple cases and have scenario where two or more scenario can match , so i am trying to concatenate all those matching cases

Comment: @SqlProgrammer why *concatenate*? Which scenarios? Perhaps you need a TVP, perhaps you need STRING_AGG. It's impossible to say given the query's code

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using a case but can be done easily using if statements...

```
declare @result varchar(200)
set @result=''

if (1=1) 
   set @result = @result+'CASE 1' 

if(1=2)
    set @result=@result+'CASE 2' 

if (2=2)
    set @result=@result+'CASE 3'



print @result
```

Comment: Then how can i display the result in select statement ?

Comment: simply by writing select @result

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CASE does not work like this in SQL Server. CASE returns one value only, and the assignment is outside the case. Also, whenever a CASE is matched, the CASE statement terminates. For example, consider this CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN 1 = 1
        THEN 1
    WHEN 1 = 2
        THEN 2
    WHEN 2 = 2
        Then 22
END
```

The output of this will be 1, because after the first match, the CASE statement exits.

You will need to use multiple IF statements instead of nested CASE statements if you need output from more than one of the CASEs, i.e.:

```
IF 1=1 then @result=@result+'CASE 1' 
IF 1=2 then @result=@result+'CASE 2' 
IF 2=2 then @result=@result+'CASE 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` like this:

```
select @result = @result +
                 (case when 1=1 then 'CASE 1' else '' end) +
                 (case when 1=2 then 'CASE 2' else '' end) +
                 (case when 2=2 then 'CASE 3' else '' end) ;
```